# Issue with custom tableviewcell imageview and accessory view

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I'm using customized tableviewcell and adding image view to the cell.  When I'm trying to add accessory discloser indicator to that cell,  the accessory view's background is changing to gray color(which is default).

Please see this image [image: Cell]

Can any one tell the solution for this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the default color or any color you want:

```
cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
```

(or)

```
cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
```

Comment: Try to avoid `[UIColor clearColor]` on `UITableViewCells` as it impacts scroll speed negatively due to the extra blending that needs to be done.

Answer (score 1):

Set the background colour of the cell in `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`, e.g.:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
}
```